# reproducible results use import-world export-world in netlogo from r

Tags: r, import, export, netlogo

I am running Netlogo from R, i want to update one parameter each time before each run. I start with each time same random seed, i setup netlogo from tick zero, use export-world to export the results, then run import-world, update one paramter, then output use export-world (ticks=1), here give the identical results. However, when start after tick 1, run import-world, update one paramter, then output use export-world (ticks=2), here gives the results not the same as run directly 2 years without update one parameter. 
Here is the code i am using:

```
#Try to get quickmodel running

options( java.parameters = "-Xmx10g" )
library(rJava)
library(RNetLogo)
require(RNetLogo)

set.seed(-986131948)
nl.path     <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/NetLogo 5.2.0"

model.path  <- ".xxxx.nlogo"

my.netlogo <-"_xxxx.nlogo"
NLStart(nl.path, gui=F, nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLLoadModel(model.path, nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand("setup", nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand('export-world "setup.csv" ', nl.obj=my.netlogo) 

# here tick=0
NLCommand('Import-world "setup.csv" ', nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand("updatedoneparamter", nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand("go", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
ticks <- NLReport("ticks", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
print(ticks)
NLCommand('export-world "go.csv" ', nl.obj=my.netlogo) #save all the results from first year run

 #start tick =1
NLCommand('Import-world "go.csv" ', nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
#NLCommand("random-seed -986131948", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
NLCommand("updatedoneparamter", nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand("go", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
ticks <- NLReport("ticks", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
print(ticks)  # tick=2
NLCommand('export-world "go.csv" ', nl.obj=my.netlogo)
```

### this give the not same results as running the code as below

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx10g" )
library(rJava)
library(RNetLogo)
require(RNetLogo)

set.seed(-986131948)
nl.path     <- "C:/Program Files (x86)/NetLogo 5.2.0"

model.path  <- "_xxxx.nlogo"

my.netlogo <-"_xxxx.nlogo"
NLStart(nl.path, gui=F, nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLLoadModel(model.path, nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand("setup", nl.obj=my.netlogo) 
NLCommand("updatedoneparamter", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
NLCommand(2,"go", nl.obj=my.netlogo)
```

#### note that in order to test the script, the updatedoneparamter is the same for each run

is anyone know why i have different results? since i start with same random-seed.

Thanks
Shanghua

Answer (score 2):

You have the same seed in R (using `set.seed`) but NetLogo uses a separate random number generator with its own independent seed. To set the NetLogo seed, use `NLCommand("random-seed 0", nl.obj=my.netlogo)`. The NetLogo documentation for `random-seed` can be found [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-seed).

Edit:
I didn't have notice at first that you are running `setup` and `go` before setting the NetLogo random seed. This will lead to divergent world conditions at the time you export the world (and divergent results). To get exactly reproducible results you should set the random seed immediately after loading the NetLogo model, before running `setup`, `go`, or any other procedures.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use the NLCommand with set random seed in r, however, it is still give different results between using import-world, export-world, and running continuously.

Comment: `export-world` saves the random state at the time of export and `import-world` loads that state. Setting the random seed and running continuously will give different results unless `export-world` was seeded in the same way (and carries out exactly the same operations) as running continuously.

Comment: Hi, I understand it, but how it do it in R?  However, I tried with solved the problem by running python script in R with rPython, it works for me. I did not figure a way how to do it with import/export world, if anyone knows it would be helpful for who have the same problem with me. Thanks

Comment: I've just edited my response, hopefully with some helpful information - the command to set the netlogo random-seed needs to be run immediately after loading the model in *both cases*, not after running `setup` and `go`.

Comment: Thanks very much, Robert, however it is still not working, not producing the same results even i always put NLCommand("random-seed 0", nl.obj=my.netlogo) everytime after i load the model, before any commands. I found another solution, though, that running everything (python script) in r instead of trying run rscript in python.